# Object Array As Parameter to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to send object array as parameter to MVC Controller?

```
public class FeedStats
{
    public long FeedId { get; set; }
    public ApiType ApiType { get; set; }
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public float ReadTime { get; set; }
    public long FeedIndex { get; set; }
    public bool IsWebRead { get; set; }
}
```

In Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateFeedStats(FeedStats[] data)
{
}
```

When i make `HttpPost` request with `Postman` with these parameters, the data is always null. Whats an issue?

Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json

{
data: [
   FeedId: 1,
   ApiType: 1,
   UserId: 1,
   ReadTime: 0.65,
   FeedIndex: 1,
   IsWebRead: 1
]
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you are making the request?

Comment: i updated my question with request headers. pls check.

Comment: @haim770, Thanks it works, hi can u pls post that as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `FeedStats[]` is an array of **Objects**. you need to enclose the inner object with curly braces as well:

```
{
data:[
     {FeedId:1,...},
     {...},
     {...}
     ]
}
```